# Intersection of vector subspaces and extension of the ground field.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$ and $\{W_i\}_{i\in I}$ a collection of subspaces of $V$. Let $K$ be an extension field of $F$. If $I$ is finite then it is easy to see that $$\big(\bigcap_{i\in I} W_i\big)\otimes_F K=\big(\bigcap_{i\in I} W_i\otimes_F K \big).$$ 
Is this true also when $I$ is infinite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will use the followig fact about the tensor product of $F$-vector spaces.

> **Lemma:**
>   Let $V, U$ be $F$-vector spaces and let $(u_j)_{j \in J}$ be an $F$-basis of $U$.
>   Then every $x \in V \otimes_F U$ can be written as $x = \sum_{j \in J} v_j \otimes u_j$ for unique elements $v_j \in V$ (with $v_j = 0$ for all but finitely many $j \in J$).
>
> *Proof:*
>   We have that $U = \bigoplus_{j \in J} \langle u_j \rangle_F$ and therefore
>   $$
>       V \otimes_F U
> =     V \otimes_F \left( \bigoplus_{j \in J} \langle u_j \rangle_F \right)
> =     \bigoplus_{j \in J} ( V \otimes_F  \langle u_j \rangle_F )
> =     \bigoplus_{j \in J} (V \otimes u_j)
> \cong \bigoplus_{j \in J} V,
> $$
>   where $\langle u \rangle_F = \{\lambda u \mid \lambda \in F\}$ denotes the $F$-span of $u \in U$.

We can now prove the statement itself by showing both inclusions:

For every $j \in I$ we have that $\bigcap_{i \in I} W_i \subseteq W_j$, therefore
$$
            \left( \bigcap_{i \in I} W_i \right) \otimes_F K
  \subseteq W_j \otimes_F K,
$$
and thus alltogether
$$
            \left( \bigcap_{i \in I} W_i \right) \otimes_F K
  \subseteq \bigcap_{j \in I} (W_j \otimes_F K).
$$

For the other inclusion let $x \in \bigcap_{i \in I} (W_i \otimes_F K)$, and let $(b_j)_{j \in J}$ be an $F$-basis of $K$.
By using that $x \in V \otimes_F K$ we may write
$$
    x
  = \sum_{j \in J} v_j \otimes b_j
$$
for unique elements $v_j \in V$.
For every $i \in I$ it similarly follows from $x \in W_i \otimes_F K$ that
$$
    x
  = \sum_{j \in J} w^i_j \otimes b_j
$$
for unique elements $w^i_j \in W_i$.
For every $j \in J$ it follows from the uniqueness of these decompositions that $v_j = w^i_j \in W_i$ for every $i \in I$, and therefore that $v_j \in \bigcap_{i \in I} W_i$.
It thus follows that
$$
      x
  =   \sum_{j \in J} v_j \otimes b_j
  \in \left( \bigcap_{i \in I} W_i \right) \otimes_F K \,.
$$
This shows the other inclusion.

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but I don't have as nice an argument as one might want, seemingly because "intersection" as categorical object has the natural maps going *to* it, rather than *from*, while the tensor product has maps going the opposite direction...?

But, nevertheless, the intersection has a basis (Axiom of Choice?), and extends to a basis of each $W_i$. It is not hard to prove that an "extension of scalars" of a free module produces a free module with "the same" generators, in the sense that they are images of the originals.

Thus, the intersection of the $W_i\otimes_F K$'s is no larger than the tensor product with the intersection.